# How can I push an image to an Azure Container Registry on a different account than the ADO Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry, serviceconnection

On My ADO account, I have created a service account of Azure Resource Manager but it doesn't work with this task.

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push image to ACR
  inputs:
  command: push
  containerRegistry: 'MyAZConnection' # Your service connection name

The pipeline is not valid. Job Build: Step Docker2 input containerRegistry expects a service connection of type dockerregistry but the provided service connection MyAZConnection is of type azurerm.

If I create a new Docker Registry Service Connection, it only connects to a subscription within the same Microsoft account.

Is there some alternate way to push this image to ACR in different azure account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default,  Docker@2 only supports the **dockerregistry type** service connection.

Based on your requirement, you need to use the Azure Resource Manager Service Connection to deploy to different account.  You can create a **Manual type** of Azure Resource Manager Service Connection.

You can change to use the Docker@1 or Docker@0 Task to use the Azure Resource Manager Service Connection.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'Push an image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: AzureRMServiceconnection
    azureContainerRegistry: containername
    command: 'Push an image'
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Docker V1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v1?view=azure-pipelines)